# Is there a way to use vcrpy for requests made from a different process?

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, vcr

I'm trying to use vcrpy to record and replay requests.

Issue is, those requests are happening on a different process and it looks like vcrpy doesn't work on that.

code looks something like this:

```
import vcr
with vcr.use_cassette("path/to/cassette"):
    A = subprocess.Popen("etc etc - a request happens here")
    A.wait()
```

When I run it the cassette does not get created.

Is there a way for me to use vcrpy to record those requests and save them?

Is there perhaps a different approach I can use for this?

Thanks